# Subversion Local Copy On Computer

Tags: eclipse, svn

I'm completely new to Subversion and need help understanding something. On a homework assignment I have, it indicates that I need to checkout a repo and make a folder in that repo my workspace in Eclipse. Problem is, I don't understand where this local copy of the repo is supposed to be on my PC so I can't find it when I hit Browse. Can anybody help and explain how this works?

Comment: You can checkout a repository anywhere on your computer. Then just import or create a new projet in Eclipse pointing to the directory you just downloaded.

Comment: You might want to let folks know *how* you checked out the local copy.

Comment: I used Cygwin, typed tcsh and did svn co https://...com. It's under [User@PC Name ~]$. Not sure where that is.

Comment: just call a `pwd` in your cygwin shell

Comment: It gives /home/users/repo folder. Where's home in Windows? Is it in the C/Users or somewhere in the cygwin folder? I can't find it under C/Users.

Comment: Do you have subversive or subclipse installed on your eclipse? Which version of eclipse are you running?